# FATAL ERROR in native method: Bad global or local ref passed to JNI

Tags: java-native-interface

I have gotten this error when setting the -Xcheck:jni option, and calling my native method.

The error is :
FATAL ERROR in native method: Bad global or local ref passed to JNI

I shall paste the native method (C code) here, hope that anybody who knows what is wrong with this piece of code, will enlighten me. Thank you.

```
    #include <stdio.h>  
    #include <stdlib.h>  
    #include <string.h>  
    #include "fns_data.h"  
    #include "fns_client.h"  
    #include "sockRW.h"  
    #include "/usr/local/include/jni.h"  
    #include "JNIiSearchLib.h"  
    #include "com_eds_wise_util_JNIiSearchLib.h"  

    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL  
    Java_com_eds_wise_util_JNIiSearchLib_jniFNSSearchClient (  
        JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring jip_addr, jint jport_number,  
        jstring jfield, jstring jquery_str, jint jhitnum)  
    {  
        HitIds           *hit_list   = NULL;  
        hitListPktStruct *hitPkt     = NULL;  
        int               hit_number = 0;  
        int               i          = 0;  
        int               fnsErrno   = 0;  
        char             *result_str = NULL;  
        jstring          *rslt_str   = NULL;  
        const char       *cip_addr   = NULL;  
        const char       *cquery_str = NULL;  
        char              errbuf[1024];  

        cip_addr   = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jip_addr, 0);  
        if (cip_addr == NULL) {  
            return ((* env)->NewStringUTF (env, "Error: Cannot get IP address."));  
        }  

        cquery_str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jquery_str, 0);  
        if (cquery_str == NULL) {  
            (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jip_addr, cip_addr);  
            (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cip_addr);  
            return ((* env)->NewStringUTF (env, "Error: Cannot get query string."));  
        }  
        printf ("[Java_JNILib_jniFNSSearchClient] ipaddress[%s] portnumber[%d]"  
                " querystr[%s]\n\n", cip_addr, jport_number, cquery_str);  

        /* Search and get back the handler & total hits 
         */  
        hit_list = fns_search_client0 (cip_addr, jport_number,  
                                       "PN", cquery_str, &hit_number);  


        /* Display total hits 
         */  
        printf ("Total hits = %d\n", hit_number);  


        /* Enumerate every item in the result list and display them. 
         * The results are returned as a string to Java in the following manner: 
         * 
         * "[hitresult1|hitresult2|hitresult3|..|hitresultN]\0" 
         * 
         *     where hitresultN = 94-byte record 
         * 
         * [+string94+|+string94]+stringTerminator  
         */  
        printf ("malloc[%d]\n", (hit_number * 95) + 3);  

        result_str = malloc (((hit_number * 95)+3) * sizeof(char));  
        if (result_str == NULL) {  
            printf ("Out of memory, unable to malloc\n");  
            rslt_str = (* env)->NewStringUTF (env, "Error: Out of memory, unable to malloc");  

            if (hit_list) {  
                FREE_STRING (hit_list);  
            }  
            if (hitPkt) {  
                FREE_HITLIST_STRUCT (hitPkt);  
            }  
            (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jip_addr, cip_addr);  
            (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jquery_str, cquery_str);  
            (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cip_addr);  
            (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cquery_str);  

            fflush(stdout);  
            return (rslt_str);  
        }  

        sprintf (result_str, "[");  
        for (i = 0; i < hit_number; i++) {  
            strcat (result_str, hitPkt->docNameList[i]);  
            if (i != (hit_number - 1)) {  
                strcat (result_str, "|");  
            }  
        }  
        strcat (result_str, "]");  

        printf ("\n\nFNS search result:[From Library]\n");  
        printf ("%s\n\n",result_str);  

        /* free the handler 
         */  
        if (hit_list) {  
            FREE_STRING (hit_list);  
        }  

        /* free the result lists 
         */  
        if (hitPkt) {  
            FREE_HITLIST_STRUCT (hitPkt);  
        }  

        /* prepare stuff for Java 
         */  
        rslt_str = (* env)->NewStringUTF (env, result_str);  

        /* free our memory 
         */  
        if (result_str) {  
            free (result_str);  
        }  
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jip_addr, cip_addr);  
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jquery_str, cquery_str);  
        (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cip_addr);  
        (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cquery_str);  

        fflush(stdout);  
        return (rslt_str);  
    }
```

Comment: weili, this is a lot of code to ask someone to wade through.  You'll get a reply much more quickly if you boil it down to a smaller reproduction case.  For example can you reproduce the crash when fns_error_message is zero?  If so, remove the error check and the "if (fnsErrno)" block. Also, can you reproduce it when hit_number is 0?  If so, you can rip out the "if (hit_number > 0)" block of code, as well.

Comment: hi bob, i have followed your advice, and trimmed down the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder how this even compiles. `jstring` is a pointer type already, so yours

```
jstring          *rslt_str   = NULL;
```

is a pointer to pointer, and i wonder how the compiler can take it as retval for `GetStringUTFChars` and `return`ing it from your native method altogether.

Comment: Thanks.. So I should declare rslt_str as jstring type instead of pointer to jstring ? I think you are saying retrieval for "NewStringUTF" and "return" ... instead of saying retrieval for "GetStringUTFChars" and "return" ? Thanks..

Comment: Yes exactly. Though i am not completely sure how `rslt_str` is a "bad ref passed to JNI"... post your findings here.

Comment: Hi Pavel, my colleague has made other changes to the above code, which solved the "bad local glocal ref passed to JNI" , but the code is still having memory leak ( when we invoke this native method + run other requests ... jvm will crash ) , so we tried removing the pointer to jstring type as you suggested, but memory leak still exists... I shall edit the above to the latest code we implemented, and hope if anyone knows how to catch the memory leak in this code , thanks so far pavel :)

Comment: If the current answer has solved your current question with "bad ref passed", then accept the answer and create a new question with a different description. Your new problem is a memory leak, not a bad ref. Don't confuse the readers.

Comment: this "bad ref passed" error has been solved by my colleague, apparently it is some complication error, (i) he commented off all the DeleteLocalRef jni functions, and (ii) cast some of the arguments to its types in the jni functions.. for example from: hit_list = fns_search_client0 (cip_addr, jport_number,  
                                       "PN", cquery_str, &hit_number);  to: hit_list = fns_search_client0 ((char *)cip_addr, jport_number,
            "PN", (char *)cquery_str, &hit_number);

Comment: however, pavel has made a very good point above, and i have incorporated his changes to the code, but the memory leak still exists, i will be opening up another question to diagnose the "memory leak" of this native C code. Thanks pavel.

Comment: thanks everybody, the new question i have is on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912619/memory-leak-on-jni-native-code