# Memory leak on JNI native code

Tags: java, c, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

I have a piece of JNI native code. When we invoked this native method + run other requests, the jvm will crash.

Most probably, there is memory leak in this piece of JNI native method ( c code).

Any body can help detect the memory leak in the below code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "fns_data.h"
#include "fns_client.h"
#include "sockRW.h"
#include "/usr/local/include/jni.h"
#include "JNIiSearchLib.h"
#include "com_eds_wise_util_JNIiSearchLib.h"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_eds_wise_util_JNIiSearchLib_jniFNSSearchClient (
    JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring jip_addr, jint jport_number,
    jstring jfield, jstring jquery_str, jint jhitnum)
{
    HitIds           *hit_list   = NULL;
    hitListPktStruct *hitPkt     = NULL;
    int               hit_number = 0;
    int               i          = 0;
    int               fnsErrno   = 0;
    char             *result_str = NULL;
    jstring          rslt_str   = NULL;
    const char          *cip_addr   = NULL;
    const char          *cquery_str = NULL;
    char              errbuf[1024];

    cip_addr   = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jip_addr, 0);
    if (cip_addr == NULL) {
        return ((* env)->NewStringUTF (env, "Error: Cannot get IP address."));
    }

    cquery_str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jquery_str, 0);
    if (cquery_str == NULL) {
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jip_addr, cip_addr);
        //(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cip_addr);
        return ((* env)->NewStringUTF (env, "Error: Cannot get query string."));
    }
    printf ("[Java_JNILib_jniFNSSearchClient] ipaddress[%s] portnumber[%d]"
            " querystr[%s]\n\n", cip_addr, jport_number, cquery_str);

    /* Search and get back the handler & total hits
     */
    hit_list = fns_search_client0 ((char *)cip_addr, jport_number,
                                   "PN", (char *)cquery_str, &hit_number);
    fnsErrno = fns_error_message();
    if (fnsErrno) {
        printf ("Error %d during fns_search_client0()\n", fnsErrno);
        sprintf (errbuf, "Error: fns_search_client0() returns %d.", fnsErrno);

        rslt_str = (* env)->NewStringUTF (env, errbuf);

        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jip_addr, cip_addr);
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jquery_str, cquery_str);
        //(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cip_addr);
        //(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cquery_str);

        fflush(stdout);
        return (rslt_str);
    }

    /* Display total hits
     */
    printf ("Total hits = %d\n", hit_number);

    /* Use the handler as parameter to retrieve the actual result
     */
    if (hit_number > 0) {
        fns_display_ids0 ((char *)cip_addr, jport_number, hit_list,
                          0, hit_number - 1, &hitPkt);
        fnsErrno = fns_error_message();
        if (fnsErrno) {
            printf ("Error %d during fns_display_ids0()\n", fnsErrno);
            sprintf (errbuf, "Error: fns_display_ids0() returns %d.", fnsErrno);
            rslt_str = (* env)->NewStringUTF (env, errbuf);

            if (hit_list) {
                FREE_STRING (hit_list);
            }
            (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jip_addr, cip_addr);
            (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jquery_str, cquery_str);
            //(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cip_addr);
            //(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cquery_str);

            fflush(stdout);
            return (rslt_str);
        }
    }

    /* Enumerate every item in the result list and display them.
     * The results are returned as a string to Java in the following manner:
     *
     * "[hitresult1|hitresult2|hitresult3|..|hitresultN]\0"
     *
     *     where hitresultN = 94-byte record
     *
     * [+string94+|+string94]+stringTerminator 
     */
    printf ("malloc[%d]\n", (hit_number * 95) + 3);

    result_str = malloc (((hit_number * 95)+3) * sizeof(char));
    if (result_str == NULL) {
        printf ("Out of memory, unable to malloc\n");
        rslt_str = (* env)->NewStringUTF (env, "Error: Out of memory, unable to malloc");

        if (hit_list) {
            FREE_STRING (hit_list);
        }
        if (hitPkt) {
            FREE_HITLIST_STRUCT (hitPkt);
        }
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jip_addr, cip_addr);
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jquery_str, cquery_str);
        //(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cip_addr);
        //(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cquery_str);

        fflush(stdout);
        return (rslt_str);
    }

    sprintf (result_str, "[");
    for (i = 0; i < hit_number; i++) {
        strcat (result_str, hitPkt->docNameList[i]);
        if (i != (hit_number - 1)) {
            strcat (result_str, "|");
        }
    }
    strcat (result_str, "]");

    printf ("\n\nFNS search result:[From Library]\n");
    printf ("%s\n\n",result_str);

    /* free the handler
     */
    if (hit_list) {
        FREE_STRING (hit_list);
    }

    /* free the result lists
     */
    if (hitPkt) {
        FREE_HITLIST_STRUCT (hitPkt);
    }

    /* prepare stuff for Java
     */
    rslt_str = (* env)->NewStringUTF (env, result_str);

    /* free our memory
     */
    if (result_str) {
        free (result_str);
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jip_addr, cip_addr);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, jquery_str, cquery_str);
    //(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cip_addr);
    //(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, cquery_str);

    fflush(stdout);
    return (rslt_str);
}
```

Comment: debug. Use dmalloc or similar tool to see where the leaking might be.

Comment: @weili: A memory leak will no crash your application unless you run it for an extended period of time and eventually run out of memory. You're more likely to have freed the same piece of memory twice, accessed memory outside the allocated area or not properly initialized some data structure.

Comment: @weili: Could it be that search library holds on to *cip_addr* passed to fns_display_ids0() after the JNI method has returned? Or that the hit lists have a reference to Java query string and free it? Or that the search library has a memory problem?

Comment: @Codo Thanks Codo, I am looking into all these as possible causes..

Comment: @Codo I found out that I am passing jport_number (which is of jint type) directly into fns_search_client0 and fns_display_ids0. Is this the problem causing the jvm crash? I think I should convert this jport_number to the type of C native int first, before passing into these 2 functions? Hence, I will do this declaration: int    cport_number = (int)jport_number , and then pass cport_number (instead of jport_number) into the 2 functions ? What do you think?

Comment: It's unlikely that an integer type causes a memory problem. It must be a data structure that involves pointers. If you have a correct and complete declaration of `fns_search_client0`, then it's even impossible since they compiler either warns you or converts mismatching integer types automatically.

Comment: I am curious as to what FREE_STRING and FREE_HITLIST_STRUCT do.

Comment: @EJP, #define FREE_STRING(ptr) \
        { \
            free(ptr); \
            ptr=NULL; \
        }

Comment: @EJP  #define FREE_HITLIST_STRUCT(ptr) \
  { \
  FREE_LONG(ptr->docNameLen); \
  FREE_STRING_ARRAY(ptr->docNameList, ptr->numRtn); \
  FREE_LONG(ptr->docIdList); \
  FREE_STRING(ptr); \
  }

Comment: seems like there no more solutions, i have looked into all possible causes listed by all of you... any more ideas guys? thanks..

Comment: Is `fns_search_client0()` linked to the same C library that this code is linked to? If not, it is allocating memory that you are freeing with a different C library, which will definitely cause problems. Are you sure there isn't a method provided to free the result of these FNS functions?